# How to show the text of D3 node on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, data-visualization

I am very new to D3 and I am trying to replicate the behavior for text like is done with the circle elements here with the mouseover,mouseout behavior. Basically, to show text when hovered and hidden when not. Do I need to create a node var as I have with circle and text or is it possible with the current implementation:

```js
var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, value: link.type});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target, value: link.type});
});

var width = 1000,
    height = 900;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(90)
    .charge(-125)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
  .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; })
    .style("stroke", function(d){ 

      if (d.type >= 0.4) {
        return '#000066'
      }

      if (d.type >= 0.25) {
        return '#ccccff'
      }

      if (d.type >= 0.01) {
        return 'e8f4f8'
      }
      else {
        return '#FFFFFF'
      }
    });  

var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .on("dblclick", dblclick)
    .on('mouseover', function(d){
    var nodeSelection = d3.select(this).style({opacity:'0.5'});
    nodeSelection.select("text").style({opacity:'1.0'});
})
    .on('mouseout', function(d){
    var nodeSelection = d3.select(this).style({opacity:'0.0'});
    nodeSelection.select("text").style({opacity:'0.0'});
})
    .call(force.drag);

var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .text(function(d){ 
      if (d.value >= 0.35){
        return d.name
    }
  });

// Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
function tick() {
  path.attr("d", linkArc);
  circle.attr("transform", transform);
  text.attr("transform", transform);
}

function linkArc(d) {
  var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
      dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
      dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}


function transform(d) {
  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}

var drag = force.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstart);

function dblclick(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = false);
}

function dragstart(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add opacity attribute to your text that defaults to 0. It appears you already have text to show and hide it on mouseover/mouseout. I posted a different way to do it as well if your method is not working for you.

```
var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .attr("opacity", 1)
    .text(function(d){ 
      if (d.value >= 0.35){
        return d.name
    }
  });



function mouseout(d) {  text.style("opacity",  0); }
function mouseover(d) { text.style("opacity", 1);
```